# Why does a larger stack increase .bss with factor 4?

Tags: c, memory-management, stack

I'm currently working on an embedded project (STM32F103RB, CooCox CoIDE v.1.7.6 with arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.8 2013q4). I have a plain project:

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the following code (excerpt from `startup_stm32f10x_md.c`) to set the stack size

```
#define STACK_SIZE       0x00001000 
__attribute__ ((section(".co_stack")))
unsigned long pulStack[STACK_SIZE];
```

In my understanding .bss is a section in the RAM after .text  but before .heap and .stack holding uninitialized data. So .bss should **NOT** be affected by increasing the stack size. But .bss **IS** in this case. So maybe the .co_stack is a kind of user defined stack? But what I really don't get: Which does .bss grow 4 times the stack size? e.g.

```
#define STACK_SIZE       0x00001000 
.bss 16384 = 0x4000
```

or

```
#define STACK_SIZE       0x00000100 
.bss 1024 = 0x400
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy of startup_stm32f10x_md.c I found on the net defines the stack as array of longs (which is advisable to keep it long word aligned).

```
static unsigned long pulStack[STACK_SIZE];
```

0x1000 longs add up to 4096 x 4 = 16K.

Comment: that matches the line `unsigned long pulStack[STACK_SIZE];` but doesn't explain why the stack increases .bss

Comment: This depends of the contents of the linker script. I'm not familiar with the platform, but I wouldn't expect an embedded system to implement a full featured ELF loader, so it's pretty likely that the stack is located in the .bss segment.